# ng-bootstrap ngbDropdown not working Angular 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

ng dropdowns are not working.

Note: I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111633/ng-bootstrap-ngbdropdown-not-working-in-angular-4) and upgraded bootstrap to 4-alpha, yet it's not working.

Below is my package.json file:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.28",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.8",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.19.0",
    "angular2-ladda": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.2",
    "angular2-toaster": "^4.0.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"
```

html code:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>More Actions..</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In my app.module.ts ngbModule is imported too.

```
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
//more
]
```

Bootstrap buttons and text inputs working and all the styles are applied, except for dropdown isn't working on click.

[image]

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure jquery is there as a reference?

Comment: Is your component declared in app.module.ts or in a separated module? If its a separate module, you'll need to import and export NgbModule as well.

Comment: @Aravind yeah it's in the package.json

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit my component is in a separate module and yeah I adding Ngb to that module worked! thanks. Can you tell me why it's not applied to other modules when it's imported to root? I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to ng.

Comment: @Maddy with Angular you have to import directives in _every_ module where you want to use those directives.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

NgbModule has to be imported within the separate module as well. Credits: HaveSpacesuit

Answer (score 4):

add ngb modules you use,
NgbModule has to be imported....

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
        ..,
        NgbModule.forRoot()
   ],
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

@Maddy
Just make some minor change to your html code:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>More Actions..</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownMenu >
                    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

> **ngbDropdownMenu** is property added to "dropdown-menu" div.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of ng-bootstrap, either import `NgbDropdownModule` or the more comprehensive `NgbModule` into the module for the page.